# How to use regex expression as the command line argument in VSCode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

How to use regex expression as the command line argument in VSCode?

My launch.json is like:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
            {
                  "name": "Launch Package",
                  "type": "go",
                  "request": "launch",
                  "mode": "auto",
                  "program": "${file}",
                  "args": ["wc.so", "pg*.txt"]
            }
      ]
```

There are a list of filenames start with pg and I want all of their filenames as the arguments.
But it only finds the file with the filename "pg*.txt".

Comment: then the program using that argument must support wildcards, VSC is not a shell expanding the wildcard like bash